# is there a way to use a variable in another method without using a parameter?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, switch-statement

there is a variable called (**limitOfPassengers**) in the first method called (**addFlight**), asking the user to enter a number for the limit then save it in the variable.
then i want to use this input in another method called (**addPassengerToTheFlight**) with an if statement to check if the added passengers doesn't exceed the given limit number.

if i use a parameter in the second method there will be an error on a **switch** method.
What should i do?

The code is too long
but here are the codes issue

```js
 switch (choice) {
                case 1: {
                    airway.addFlight();
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Detail of Passenger");
                    airway.addPassengersToFlight();
                    break;

                }
// the first method
public void addFlight()
    {
int limitOfpassengers;
System.out.print("Enter passenger limit:   ");
        limitOfpassengers=ss.nextInt();
}

//the second method

    public void addPassengersToFlight() {
if (flight.getPassengerLimit() <= limitOfpassengers) {
                flight.addPassengers(passengers);
                System.out.println("New Passenger is Added!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("!!!No More Space for Passenger!!!");
            }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the code to figure out what the problem is.  Please post what you are having trouble with.

Comment: Some code would be helpful, as markspace says. But it sounds like you may just need a field in your class. Show what you have and where you are stuck.

Comment: Sounds like you should use a parameter in the second method.  What error are you getting in your switch, and can you show us the method so that we can give advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Always share the code, don't explain it ;)

Comment: @markspace
i added some codes

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem
if i added a parameter in the second method

this code gives an error
'case 2: {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tPlease Enter Detail of Passenger");
                    airway.addPassengersToFlight();
                    break;'

an error says 
the method **addPassengersToFlight** cannot be applied to given types;
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: @erickson i added some codes

Comment: If you add a parameter to your method, you have to pass the value of it when you call the method.  That error is nothing to do with your switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a way to use a variable in another method without using a parameter?*

Yes.  Here is one way:

```java
public class MyClass {

  private int myVar;

  public MyClass() {
    myVar = 0;
  }

  public void incrementMyVar() {
    myVar++;
  }
  
  public int getMyVar() {
    return myVar;
  }
}
```

The specific issue you have in your provided code is that the scope of `limitOfPassengers` is limited to the `addFlight()` method.  Search for "java variable scope" for more details.

Comment: While technically correct, I don't think this answer is the best thing to show a beginner who's learning how to pass parameters between methods.  Otherwise, they'll end up learning to code in a style where everything is stored in fields, and that has huge maintainability issues once a class becomes complicated.